# Remove multiple numbers from an ArrayList

Tags: java, arrays, loops, arraylist

I've got this exercise "**Write a program that constructs an ArrayList containing the numbers 1 to 100 and prints them out. Then ask the user for a number, and remove all multiples of that number (except for the number itself) from the list, and print the list out again. For example, if the user selects 5, it will remove 10, 15, 20, 25, 30, etc from the list."**

And I can't seem to be done with the second part (removing all multiples)

So far this is what I've got:

```java
package ArrayList1To100;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class OneToHundreed {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        ArrayList<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>();

        for (int i = 1; i <= 100; i++) {
            list.add(i);
        }
        System.out.println(list);
        System.out.println("Next part of the exercise\n_________________________");
        System.out.println("Please enter a number");
        final int input = sc.nextInt();

        int i = 2;
        int x = i * input;
        while (list.contains(x)) {
            list.remove(x - 1);
        }
        System.out.println(list);

    }
}
```

I get that my remove part is flawed as it only removes a single number.
I've tried with an if statement, and a while. But I can't seem to find the connection.

Comment: Ask yourself how you get all multiples of a given number. You know that your list is from `1` to `100`. So ... if the user inputs `5`, how do you get all multiples of `5` between `1` and `100`? When you got that, you just have to do `list.remove(multiple);` and you're done. Try to describe it in simple words, step by step. Then you'll see that you can convert those steps into code quite easy.

Comment: Yes. I'ts just a "basic" exercise for my study.

Comment: Will look through tihs. Thank you.
@BenjaminM, good point. Will try see the step by step

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [modulo operation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulo_operation).

Code:

```java
System.out.println(list);
System.out.println("Next part of the exercise\n_________________________");
System.out.println("Please enter a number");
final int input = sc.nextInt();
// The result array that will contain correct numbers.
ArrayList<Integer> result = new ArrayList<>();
// For loop roams the initial dataset starting from first index.
for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
    // If the element in the initial array list is equal to
    // the input number, it will directly added to the result
    // array list.
    if (list.get(i) == input) {
        result.add(list.get(i));
    }
    // Otherwise, the modulo operation will be executed.
    // If the result of the modulo is greater than 0,
    // the number will be added to the result array list.
    else if ((list.get(i) % input) > 0) {
        result.add(list.get(i));
    }
}
System.out.println(result);
```

Comment: This will remove the `input` itself as well.

Comment: @Alex Yeap, I fixed it. Thank you.

Comment: Voted up, specifically for creating a new list for the result. Modifying the initial list in a loop is a bad idea. There is also one additional problem in this task: the list contains Integers. So it might not be obvious at a glance what does `list.remove(7)` do - removes the seventh element or removes an element with value 7. Thus creation of another list as a result is a proper way.

Comment: Ah yes, true, the condition should be `if (list.get(i) == input || (list.get(i) % input) > 0) {` and then you should do `result.add(list.get(i))`. But the idea is solid

Comment: Hi again, I tested it now and I fixed my mistakes. Thank you all for your comments!

Comment: The original number is still gone from the list

Comment: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 11, 12, 13, 14, 16, 17, 18, 19, 21, 22,....] is the result now.

Comment: This is really helpful! Thank you all!

Comment: Will definitely do that. Gotta be able to read it afterwards ;)

Comment: @Malthe22 That's nice to hear that it helped you. I also added some comments that makes the function clear.

Answer (score 1):

This isn't the entire program but enough to give you the idea.  It uses `removeIf` and the condition is that the number is divisible by the input but not equal to the input itself.

```
int input = 2;
List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>(List.of(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10));
System.out.println(list);
list.removeIf(a->a != input && a % input == 0);
System.out.println(list);
```

Prints

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
[1, 2, 3, 5, 7, 9]
```

Comment: Appreciate the input. I don't get the "a ->a" however?
Haven't been working with removeIf yet

Comment: for any value in the list `a`, apply `a` to the conditions.  It's a lambda expression.

Comment: I see we came up with basically the same solution. Mine admittedly took longer to write than yours. :)

Comment: Your code does not compile, though, as the `List` interface does not provide that `of()` method... At least not in JDK 8, which I'm still stuck on :P

Comment: introduced in java 9

Comment: @Zephyr Java is already at JDK 15 so I don't caveat those any more than I caveated generics (from JDK 1.5) to folks who might have been running JDK 1.4.  And it isn't essential to the solution. Just a way to initialize a list.

Answer (score 1):

This may be a bit more advanced than your class wants you to go right now, but the `List` interface provides a `removeIf()` method that allows you to remove all elements of the `List` that match a certain condition.

Since you want to remove all numbers that are multiples of your input, you would just check for that using the modulo operator: `%`.

We add a second condition to account for the original `input` so it doesn't also get removed:

```
list.removeIf(integer -> (integer % input == 0 && integer != input));
```

The odd syntax (`integer ->`) is what is called a *lambda expression*. They are a fairly advanced topic, but essentially what is happening is `integer` is the item in the `List`. We are "passing" that reference to our conditional statements so it can be used in the calculation.

So it's basically saying "for each `integer`, do this `->`."  Lambdas are a feature of Java that allows you to write cleaner and more readable code.  They are "shortcuts" to longer code, if you will.

Here is the exact same process, but written out without using the lambda shortcut:

```
list.removeIf(new Predicate<Integer>() {
    @Override
    public boolean test(Integer integer) {
         return integer % input == 0 && integer != input;
    }
});
```

The `integer % input == 0` returns `true` if `integer ÷ input` leaves no remainder (ie: it is a multiple of the `input`).

Given your code, our final output for the input of `5` is this:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 11, 12, 13, 14, 16, 17, 18, 19, 21, 22, 23, 24, 26, 27, 28, 29, 31, 32, 33, 34, 36, 37, 38, 39, 41, 42, 43, 44, 46, 47, 48, 49, 51, 52, 53, 54, 56, 57, 58, 59, 61, 62, 63, 64, 66, 67, 68, 69, 71, 72, 73, 74, 76, 77, 78, 79, 81, 82, 83, 84, 86, 87, 88, 89, 91, 92, 93, 94, 96, 97, 98, 99]
```

Comment: Thank you for the input. Haven't learned about removeIf as of yet. I don't understand the interger -> part. Care to explain?

Comment: I've updated my question with a little bit of an explanation. Lambdas are a more complex topic, but they're incredibly useful.

Comment: Thank you very much for the explanation. I think it might be too advanced for myself atm. But it's a nice shortcut!

Answer (score 0):

Remove every multiple of the given number. Create a for loop, starting at 0, that adds the specified number to an index on every loop iteration. If the current number is NOT the original input number, remove it from the array list.

When removing elements from the ArrayList, the index of all of the elements that come after the removed element will be shifted down by one. To counter this, we divide the current index by the input value (the value that will have all multiplies of it removed), indicating how many other values have been removed.

```
package test;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class OneToHundreed {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System. in );
        ArrayList < Integer > list = new ArrayList < >();

        for (int i = 1; i <= 100; i++) {
            list.add(i);
        }
        System.out.println(list);
        System.out.println("Next part of the exercise\n_________________________");
        System.out.println("Please enter a number");
        final int input = sc.nextInt();

        // index = 0
        // if the input is 5, the index will go like:
        // 0, 5, 10, 15, 20, 25... etc
        // if the index is 5, it won't remove the number
        // otherwise it will
        for (int index = input; index <= 100; index += input) {
            if (index != input) list.remove(index - (index / input) + 1);
        }
        System.out.println(list);
    }
}
```

Comment: This code has many problems. It starts with wrong index (zero), modifies the list on the fly and can easily generate IndexOutOfBoundsException.

Comment: @user15358848 The loop continues up to 100, but the elements are being removed from the list, so the size of the list decreases, so it's quite probable that at the end we'll try to remove an element with index smaller than 100 but larger than the current list size, which will lead to IndexOutOfBounds exception.

Comment: No, it will not. When we remove an element from the list all further elements are shifted down by 1. So if input = 5 we'll remove elements 11, 17, 23, 29, etc. You need to replace `index += input` with `index += input - 1`. So that's why I said there are many problems with the code

Comment: No, the "wrong values" in case of input 5 are "10, 15, 20, 25,...", not "11, 17, 23, 29,..."

Comment: The idea here is basically the same as [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66569346/6367213), only the other answer is much shorter and more concise.

Answer (score 0):

Not efficient, but closest to your intention and easy to understand:

```
for (Integer i = input * 2; i <= 100; i += input) {
    list.remove(i);
}
```

Note use of `Integer` for the loop variable instead of `int`. The `remove()` method comes in 2 flavours, and we don’t want the `int` version which removes the item at an *index*.

Comment: still upvoted it, liked it from the beginning

Comment: @user15358848 as per my answer, it is not efficient, but it’s simple and gets the job done.

Comment: I personally think it's a pretty clever solution, I like it, really, and I'm not drunk(yet)

Answer (score 0):

Can check it efficient way no if condition required.

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    ArrayList<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>();
    ArrayList<Integer> res = new ArrayList<>();

    for (int i = 1; i <= 100; i++) {
        list.add(i);
    }

    System.out.println("Please enter a number");

    final int input = sc.nextInt();

    for (int i = input; i <= 100; i += input) {
        res.add(i);
    }
    System.out.println(res);
}
```

Comment: Edited can check now

Answer (score 0):

I find below approch more easy:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        ArrayList<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>();

        for (int i = 1; i <= 100; i++) {
            list.add(i);
        }
        System.out.println(list);
        System.out.println("Next part of the exercise\n_________________________");
        System.out.println("Please enter a number");
        final int input = sc.nextInt();

        for(int i=0; i<list.size(); i++){
            //if element is multiple of input
            if(list.get(i)%input==0){
                //remove the element
                list.remove(i);
                //reduce iteration, so it checks the next element -> as comes to removed element position
                i--;
            }
        }
        System.out.println(list);
    }
```